# Why the Eclipse Terminal view appears empty on MAC?

Tags: eclipse, macos, console

I recently update my MAC to High Sierra version, and after that my terminal eclipse view appears empty. I'm using Eclipse Neon:

[image]

I can write commands, but I can't show it:
[image]

My Eclipse terminal configuration:
[image]

I want show again the command line where I'm writing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **known problem** that has **already** been **fixed** in the CDT PTY support for Oxygen.1:

- [Eclipse Bug 522590 - No prompt or typing output with High Sierra [Duplicate]](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522590)
- [Eclipse Bug 519886 - eclipse CDT failed to create PTY on macOS 10.13 beta](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519886)

If an **[upgrade to the latest version](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F)** version does not solve the problem, see [bug 522590, comment #1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522590#c1):

> Until then, you can add this p2 repository URL :
>   **`http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/oxygen/milestones`** in the
>   ***Help > Install New Software*** dialog. **Disable the *Group by Category***
>   and **install the *C/C++ Development Tooling Native Utilities***.

Comment: I have this Eclipse version but it doesn't work:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

Comment: This comment on the Bug-522590:

Until then, you can add this p2 repository URL :
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/oxygen/milestones
in the Help > Install New Software dialog. Disable the "Group by Category" and install the "C/C++ Development Tooling Native Utilities".

Solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, i.e blank terminal in Windows 10. Later found out that the issue is related to **Darkest Dark Theme** in eclipse. Even if you undo the theme changes it would still not work. I have re-installed the eclipse and terminal appeared.